# How to display large array of objects as a HTML table in a React app

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-table, react-virtualized

My task is to display array of objects as a table in my React app with some basic filters(date before/after etc..). Object has 5-6 fields(gender, email, status, date..). I don't want to render all objects at once, rather I want to create a virtualised table which displays 20-30 items at once and upon scrolling will display the next 20-30 items. I researched a lot about this and I found React-Virtualised, React-Table, React-Window to achieve this task.

What I don't understand is some examples suggest using React-table with react-window and some suggest React-Virtualised or react-window alone. And also React-Virtualised and React-window is built for lists and grids. But I want a table. I'm quite confused since last night as in which library is the right one for my use-case. Help me understand please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should immediately look for a library to do this for you.

You can easily do it yourself by for example putting 30 elements in a table and adding a scroll handler to the table element.

Then when the user has scrolled to the bottom, you just load more elements in.

If you want to make it even more efficient and advanced, you can re-use the 30 elements you've already created.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I can't afford so much time right now, so I'm looking for a quick solution to this. If you know any library please let me know